# Matplotlib without numpy or panda

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, matplotlib

i'm trying to creat a bar grafic using the matplotlib, but i can't use the numpy or panda.
so i'd like some help with the bars separation

here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eixo_X_ano = [78,82,86,90,94]
eixo_Y_AMM = [1.8,1.75,1.9,1.77,1.74]
eixo_Y_AMF = [1.71,1.69,1.8,1.73,1.82]


plt.title("Altura Media dos atletas que ganharam medalhas")
plt.xlabel("Anos")
plt.ylabel("Altura media")


largura = 2
plt.ylim(1,2.50)
plt.bar(eixo_X_ano - largura/2, eixo_Y_AMM, largura, label = "Masculino", color = "teal")
plt.bar(eixo_X_ano + largura/2, eixo_Y_AMF, largura, label = "Feminino", color = "r")
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(eixo_X_ano)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `numpy` is a dependency of `matplotlib`. Without using `numpy` operations between a `list` and a `float` are not vectorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using numpy, you can't do array arithmetic (that is, `eixo_X_ano - largura/2`).  You have to do it yourself:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eixo_X_ano = [78,82,86,90,94]
eixo_Y_AMM = [1.8,1.75,1.9,1.77,1.74]
eixo_Y_AMF = [1.71,1.69,1.8,1.73,1.82]

plt.title("Altura Media dos atletas que ganharam medalhas")
plt.xlabel("Anos")
plt.ylabel("Altura media")

largura = 2

x1 = [i - largura/2 for i in eixo_X_ano]
x2 = [i + largura/2 for i in eixo_X_ano]

plt.ylim(1,2.50)
plt.bar(x1, eixo_Y_AMM, largura, label = "Masculino", color = "teal")
plt.bar(x2, eixo_Y_AMF, largura, label = "Feminino", color = "r")
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(eixo_X_ano)
plt.show()
```

As Michael said, your restriction against `numpy` is silly.  Matplotlib imports numpy, so there is no cost in importing it yourself.

Comment: it's a restriction that the professor done